# FormField with validator not showing error message

Tags: flutter

I've got a FormField widget with the builder returning a DropdownButton and a validator, but the widget isn't displaying my error message when validation fails.

```
  FormField(
builder: (FormFieldState state) {
  return DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
      child: DropdownButton(
        value: _gender,
        isDense: true,
        hint: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).genderSelect),
        onChanged: (String newValue) {
          print(newValue);
          setState(() {
            _gender = newValue;
            state.didChange(newValue);
          });
        },
        items: _genders(),
      )
  );
},
initialValue: null,
validator: (value) {
  if(value == null){
    print('Gender is null');
    return AppLocalizations.of(context).genderRequired;
  }
},
```

)

[image: See?]

Comment: Add a key and validate using formKey.currentState.validate() Check: https://flutter.io/cookbook/forms/validation/

Comment: @RubensMelo The field is embedded in a Form that has a key

Comment: Did you try validate using currentState.validate() ?

Comment: @RubensMelo Yes, when the form is submitted I am running _formKey.currentState.validate().  You can see in the screenshot that the TextFormField instances are showing their errors

Comment: I have the same issue :(

Answer (score 2):

I solved it using the variable, `state` that the builder method provides.
Firstly, check if it has an error with `state.hasError` (*it changes true if validation method returned any*). Secondly, paint a widget with the error value using *state.errorText*.
My builder method looks like this:

```
builder: (FormFieldState<dynamic> state){
  return Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [

      // your widget with the value

      if ( state.hasError)...[
        Container(
          child: Text(state.errorText),
        ),
      ]

    ]
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use validate method in `FormFieldState`, it will set error message.

```dart
if (state.validate()) Text(state.errorText!)
```